# vaciar los registro de una tabla mysql con event_scheduler 24h

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Quiero Hacer que cada **24 horas** se `vacíen` los registro de una tabla desde la web.
lo que llevo en `javascript` es esto no es mucho pero es mas o menos vean la idea

```js
var now = new Date(); var hours = now.getHours();

if ((hours>=6)&&(hours<21)) txthora="se vacian registro";

document.write(txthora);
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Ya que muchos me aconsejaron usar el `event_scheduler` e creado este evento pero no me vacía las tablas.
*ya lo probé durante 24 horas*
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, sí los registros se deben vaciar cada 24 horas sin intervención de un usuario la solución es una tarea programada o cronjob (Linux) que ejecute el script.php que borra los registros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo desde la consola por ejemplo así

```
DROP EVENT `limpieza`; CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `limpieza` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2018-08-18 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO TRUNCATE TABLE `tabla que quieres que se vacie `
```

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez puedes ejecutarlo mediante `ajax` (si es lo que buscas) de la siguiente manera.

**EDIT:**

Recuerda que tu `now.getHours();` te devuelve un numero entre 0 y 23, si quieres que sea cada 24 horas, debes aplicar la lógica como `if (hours == 6){}` ya que, así estableces que el registro se vacía solo a una hora en especifico (en este caso es 6, bien puede ser esta hora 0). También cabe recalcar que en el archivo php `id` **es el nombre de la columna**, en este caso eliminaríamos la fila con nombre "registro". Si lo que queremos es eliminar los registros de la tabla completa en `borrar.php`, `where` esta de mas, quedando de la siguiente manera `delete from $tabla_db1;`

> En JavaScript.

```
var now = new Date(); 

var hours = now.getHours();

if ( hours >= 6 && hours < 21){

  $.ajax({
       url: "borrar.php",
       method: "POST",
       async: false,
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(respuesta) {
         var txthora="se vacian registro";
         document.write(txthora);
       }
  });
}
```

> Ahora, aquí el php.

```
     borrar.php
     <?php 
     // Actualizamos en función del nombre que tenemos

     $id = 'registro'; 

     include('abre_conexion.php');   

     $query = "delete from $tabla_db1 where id = '$id'";  
     $result = mysql_query($query);  

     include('cierra_conexion.php');   

     ?>
```

Comment: no funciona amigo

Comment: Ok amigo! Explico que pasa, cuando tu quieres que un registro se elimine automáticamente en una pagina sin la interacción de nadie, ya estas pidiendo un proceso que se ejecute en segundo plano del lado del servidor, por lo que necesitas ejecutar un script en php con un servidor que lo permita, lo mas sencillo es cronjobs. Aun asi hay un par de cosas que puedes seguir a [continuación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html), para trabajarlo con mysql directamente, mas la solución con `JavaScript` mas cercana que puedo ofrecerte es esa.

Comment: Si tienes problemas al ejecutar mysql en php intenta con [mysqli](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp).